# List all MSSQL servers in the network VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I am building one project which simply lists all the MSSQL servers running in the network using VB.NET. I can get the list using 'SqlDataSourceEnumerator' with the reference to .NET version 3.5.

My problem is that, 'SqlDataSourceEnumerator' is not giving me the list with reference of .NET version 4.5. So in order to run my project I need to install .NET 3.5 to OS like windows 8 and above.

I searched on the internet about it and I also got the link of [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/10156/enumerate-sql-server-instances-in-c-using-odbc) which works fine with any .NET version and uses ODBC for listing sql servers. But it is in the C# code and I am not able to understand the code.

Is there any other way to get the sql server list in VB.NET which is independent of .NET version. If no other way please help to understand and convert the code from the above given link.

**Update:**

I used the following code

```
 Dim dt As DataTable = Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()
 For Each dr In dt.Rows
     If dr.Item(1).ToString.Trim <> "" Then MsgBox(dr.Item(1).ToString)
 Next
```

Comment: No repro. Works just fine wit 4.5+. What doesn't work? Why do you assume there is a problem with .NET? You may have turned off the SQL Server Browser service. If you can't get the servers with `SqlDataSourceEnumerator` you won't get them by changing the driver. The discovery protocol is the same

Comment: Can you browse for SQL Servers at all? Have you tried to browse for network servers in the SSMS connection dialog box?

Comment: Yes i tried with SSMS and i am getting the server list there. But when i run in the pc where i don't have .net3.5 i am getting the blank list.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried retrieving an enumerator?

```
Public NotInheritable Class SqlDataSourceEnumerator _
    Inherits DbDataSourceEnumerator

Dim instance As SqlDataSourceEnumerator   

Dim dataTable As System.Data.DataTable = instance.GetDataSources()
```

Comment: yes tried this but it does not work without dot net 3.5

Comment: @ITresearcher I added something to my answer; in `.NET3.5` you need to use inheritance. [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @ITresearcher it *does* work. If you don't get any results, check your network, servers, browser service.

Comment: Your update shows code that uses `Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator`; have you tried what I wrote above? (`DbDataSourceEnumerator`)

Answer (score 1):

my vb's a bit rusty but this worked for me as long as the servers are set up to display their info publicly.

Dim t As DataTable = SqlClient.SqlClientFactory.Instance.CreateDataSourceEnumerator().GetDataSources()

[I did find this](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21931939/List-All-SQL-Servers-using-VB-NET.html)

Comment: @ITresearcher it *does* work. If you don't get any results, check your network, servers, browser service.

Answer (score 1):

The codeproject given in question works perfectly and below is the VB.Net version.

**formSQLInfoEnumeratorDemo.vb**

```
Imports WindowsApplication2.Moletrator.SQLDocumentor

Public Class formSQLInfoEnumeratorDemo

Private Sub formSQLInfoEnumeratorDemo_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub buttonSQLServerEnumerator_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonSQLServerEnumerator.Click
    GetSQLDetails(Me.listboxSQLServerInstances)
End Sub
Private Sub GetSQLDetails(SQLListBox As ListBox)
    Dim sie As New SQLInfoEnumerator()
    Try
        If SQLListBox.Name = "listboxSQLServerDatabaseInstances" Then
            SQLListBox.Items.Clear()
            sie.SQLServer = listboxSQLServerInstances.SelectedItem.ToString()
            sie.Username = textboxUserName.Text
            sie.Password = textboxPassword.Text
            SQLListBox.Items.AddRange(sie.EnumerateSQLServersDatabases())
        Else
            SQLListBox.Items.Clear()
            SQLListBox.Items.AddRange(sie.EnumerateSQLServers())
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

**SQLInfoEnumerator.vb**

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Namespace Moletrator.SQLDocumentor

Public Class SQLInfoEnumerator

    <DllImport("odbc32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function SQLAllocHandle(handleType As Short, inputHandle As IntPtr, ByRef outputHandlePtr As IntPtr) As Short
    End Function
    <DllImport("odbc32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function SQLSetEnvAttr(environmentHandle As IntPtr, attribute As Integer, valuePtr As IntPtr, stringLength As Integer) As Short
    End Function
    <DllImport("odbc32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function SQLFreeHandle(hType As Short, Handle As IntPtr) As Short
    End Function
    <DllImport("odbc32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
    Private Shared Function SQLBrowseConnect(handleConnection As IntPtr, inConnection As StringBuilder, stringLength As Short, outConnection As StringBuilder, bufferLength As Short, ByRef stringLength2Ptr As Short) As Short
    End Function

    Private Const SQL_DRIVER_STR As String = "DRIVER=SQL SERVER"
    Private Const SQL_SUCCESS As Short = 0
    Private Const SQL_HANDLE_ENV As Short = 1
    Private Const SQL_HANDLE_DBC As Short = 2
    Private Const SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION As Integer = 200
    Private Const SQL_OV_ODBC3 As Integer = 3
    Private Const SQL_NEED_DATA As Short = 99
    Private Const DEFAULT_RESULT_SIZE As Short = 1024
    Private Const START_STR As String = "{"
    Private Const END_STR As String = "}"


    ''' <summary>
    ''' A string to hold the selected SQL Server
    ''' </summary>
    Private m_SQLServer As String
    ''' <summary>
    ''' A string to hold the username
    ''' </summary>
    Private m_Username As String
    ''' <summary>
    ''' A string to hold the password
    ''' </summary>
    Private m_Password As String
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Property to set the SQL Server instance
    ''' </summary>
    Public WriteOnly Property SQLServer() As String
        Set(value As String)
            m_SQLServer = value
        End Set
    End Property
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Property to set the Username
    ''' </summary>
    Public WriteOnly Property Username() As String
        Set(value As String)
            m_Username = value
        End Set
    End Property
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Property to set the Password
    ''' </summary>
    Public WriteOnly Property Password() As String
        Set(value As String)
            m_Password = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Enumerate the SQL Servers returning a list (if any exist)
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Public Function EnumerateSQLServers() As String()
        Return RetrieveInformation(SQL_DRIVER_STR)
    End Function
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Enumerate the specified SQL server returning a list of databases (if any exist)
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Public Function EnumerateSQLServersDatabases() As String()
        Return RetrieveInformation(Convert.ToString((Convert.ToString((Convert.ToString(SQL_DRIVER_STR & Convert.ToString(";SERVER=")) & m_SQLServer) + ";UID=") & m_Username) + ";PWD=") & m_Password)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Enumerate for SQLServer/Databases based on the passed information it the string
    ''' The more information provided to SQLBrowseConnect the more granular it gets so
    ''' if only DRIVER=SQL SERVER passed then a list of all SQL Servers is returned
    ''' If DRIVER=SQL SERVER;Server=ServerName is passed then a list of all Databases on the
    ''' servers is returned etc
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="InputParam">A valid string to query for</param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Private Function RetrieveInformation(InputParam As String) As String()
        Dim m_environmentHandle As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
        Dim m_connectionHandle As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
        Dim inConnection As New StringBuilder(InputParam)
        Dim stringLength As Short = CShort(inConnection.Length)
        Dim outConnection As New StringBuilder(DEFAULT_RESULT_SIZE)
        Dim stringLength2Ptr As Short = 0

        Try
            If SQL_SUCCESS = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, m_environmentHandle, m_environmentHandle) Then
                If SQL_SUCCESS = SQLSetEnvAttr(m_environmentHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, New IntPtr(SQL_OV_ODBC3), 0) Then
                    If SQL_SUCCESS = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, m_environmentHandle, m_connectionHandle) Then
                        If SQL_NEED_DATA = SQLBrowseConnect(m_connectionHandle, inConnection, stringLength, outConnection, DEFAULT_RESULT_SIZE, stringLength2Ptr) Then
                            If SQL_NEED_DATA <> SQLBrowseConnect(m_connectionHandle, inConnection, stringLength, outConnection, DEFAULT_RESULT_SIZE, stringLength2Ptr) Then
                                Throw New ApplicationException("No Data Returned.")
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New ApplicationException("Cannot Locate SQL Server.")
        Finally
            FreeConnection(m_connectionHandle)
            FreeConnection(m_environmentHandle)
        End Try
        If outConnection.ToString() <> "" Then
            Return ParseSQLOutConnection(outConnection.ToString())
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If


    End Function
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Parse an outConnection string returned from SQLBrowseConnect
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="outConnection">string to parse</param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Private Function ParseSQLOutConnection(outConnection As String) As String()
        Dim m_Start As Integer = outConnection.IndexOf(START_STR) + 1
        Dim m_lenString As Integer = outConnection.IndexOf(END_STR) - m_Start
        If (m_Start > 0) AndAlso (m_lenString > 0) Then
            outConnection = outConnection.Substring(m_Start, m_lenString)
        Else
            outConnection = String.Empty
        End If
        Return outConnection.Split(",".ToCharArray())
    End Function
    Private Sub FreeConnection(handleToFree As IntPtr)
        If handleToFree <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, handleToFree)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the original code works fine on 4.6.1 by using `Item(0)` rather than `Item(1)`:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()
For Each dr In dt.Rows
    If dr.Item(0).ToString.Trim <> "" Then MsgBox(dr.Item(0).ToString)
Next
```

Comment: @Toni: This isn't a different question. And, in fact, it's pretty clearly proposing a solution. It suggests changing `Item(1)` to `Item(0)`, and ensuring people with this problem are using at least v4.6.1. Why do you think this is a new question?